# Is there a quicker way to make this confusion matrix table in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a confusion matrix table in R, using the following dataframe:

```
mydf <- structure(list(pred_class = c("dog", "dog", "fish", "cat", "cat", 
"dog", "fish", "cat", "dog", "fish"), true_class = c("cat", "cat", 
"dog", "cat", "cat", "dog", "dog", "cat", "dog", "fish")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

  pred_class true_class
1        dog        cat
2        dog        cat
3       fish        dog
4        cat        cat
5        cat        cat
6        dog        dog
```

I have produced code to do what I want - for every class (dog, cat or fish), say if each row is a true positive, a false positive, a true negative or a false negative.

```
conf_mat <- mydf %>%
    mutate(
        dog_conf = case_when(
            true_class == "dog" &  pred_class == "dog" ~ "TP",
            true_class == "dog" &  pred_class != "dog" ~ "FN",
            true_class != "dog" &  pred_class == "dog" ~ "FP",
            true_class != "dog" &  pred_class != "dog" ~ "TN"
        ),
        cat_conf = case_when(
            true_class == "cat" &  pred_class == "cat" ~ "TP",
            true_class == "cat" &  pred_class != "cat" ~ "FN",
            true_class != "cat" &  pred_class == "cat" ~ "FP",
            true_class != "cat" &  pred_class != "cat" ~ "TN"
        ),
        fish_conf = case_when(
            true_class == "fish" &  pred_class == "fish" ~ "TP",
            true_class == "fish" &  pred_class != "fish" ~ "FN",
            true_class != "fish" &  pred_class == "fish" ~ "FP",
            true_class != "fish" &  pred_class != "fish" ~ "TN"
        )
    )
```

However this code is very repetitive and bulky.  I'm not sure how to streamline this.  Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one option with `map` where we loop over the unique elements of the dataset, create columns with `transmute` in the loop based on the conditions specified in OP's post and bind those columns with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

map_dfc(unique(unlist(mydf)), ~ 
      mydf %>% 
           transmute(!! str_c(.x, '_conf') := 
        case_when(true_class == .x &  pred_class == .x ~ "TP",
            true_class == .x &  pred_class != .x ~ "FN",
            true_class != .x &  pred_class == .x ~ "FP",
            true_class != .x &  pred_class != .x ~ "TN"
        ))) %>% 
   bind_cols(mydf, .)
```

-output

```
#     pred_class true_class dog_conf cat_conf fish_conf
#1         dog        cat       FP       FN        TN
#2         dog        cat       FP       FN        TN
#3        fish        dog       FN       TN        FP
#4         cat        cat       TN       TP        TN
#5         cat        cat       TN       TP        TN
#6         dog        dog       TP       TN        TN
#7        fish        dog       FN       TN        FP
#8         cat        cat       TN       TP        TN
#9         dog        dog       TP       TN        TN
#10       fish       fish       TN       TN        TP
```

---

Or using `merge` on a key val dataset

```
keydat <- data.frame(pred_class = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
   true_class = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), 
  conf = c("TP", "FN", "FP", "TN"))

un1 <- unique(unlist(mydf))
mydf[paste0(un1, "_conf")] <- lapply(un1, function(x)
             merge(mydf == x, keydat, all.x = TRUE)$conf)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent answer by @akrun, if you wish to identify the status of each prediction (TP/TN/FP/FN) in order to calculate additional statistics/metrics, many of these can be provided by the [caret package](https://topepo.github.io/caret/), e.g.

```
library(caret)
mydf <- structure(list(pred_class = c("dog", "dog", "fish", "cat", "cat", 
                                      "dog", "fish", "cat", "dog", "fish"), true_class = c("cat", "cat", 
                                                                                           "dog", "cat", "cat", "dog", "dog", "cat", "dog", "fish")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                    10L), class = "data.frame")

conf_matrix <- confusionMatrix(factor(mydf$pred_class),
                               reference = factor(mydf$true_class),
                               mode = "everything")
conf_matrix
#> Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#> 
#>           Reference
#> Prediction cat dog fish
#>       cat    3   0    0
#>       dog    2   2    0
#>      fish    0   2    1
#> 
#> Overall Statistics
#>                                          
#>                Accuracy : 0.6             
#>                  95% CI : (0.2624, 0.8784)
#>     No Information Rate : 0.5             
#>     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.377           
#>                                          
#>                   Kappa : 0.3939          
#>                                          
#>  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA              
#>
#> Statistics by Class:
#>
#>                      Class: cat Class: dog Class: fish
#> Sensitivity              0.6000     0.5000      1.0000
#> Specificity              1.0000     0.6667      0.7778
#> Pos Pred Value           1.0000     0.5000      0.3333
#> Neg Pred Value           0.7143     0.6667      1.0000
#> Precision                1.0000     0.5000      0.3333
#> Recall                   0.6000     0.5000      1.0000
#> F1                       0.7500     0.5000      0.5000
#> Prevalence               0.5000     0.4000      0.1000
#> Detection Rate           0.3000     0.2000      0.1000
#> Detection Prevalence     0.3000     0.4000      0.3000
#> Balanced Accuracy        0.8000     0.5833      0.8889
```

Further explanation:

For a 2x2 table with notation

```
            Reference   
Predicted   Event   No Event
Event           A        B
No Event        C        D
```

When "A" = TP, "B" = FP, "C" = FN, "D" = TN, the formulas used by the package/function are:

- Sensitivity = A/(A+C)
- Specificity = D/(B+D)
- Prevalence = (A+C)/(A+B+C+D)
- PPV = (sensitivity * prevalence)/((sensitivity * prevalence) + ((1-specificity) * (1-prevalence)))
- NPV = (specificity * (1-prevalence))/(((1-sensitivity) * prevalence) + ((specificity) * (1-prevalence))) Detection Rate = A/(A+B+C+D)
- Detection Prevalence = (A+B)/(A+B+C+D)
- Balanced Accuracy = (sensitivity+specificity)/2 Precision = A/(A+B) Recall = A/(A+C)
- F1 = (1+beta^2) * precision * recall/((beta^2 * precision)+recall)